# Mockito not working for a Boolean Function

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have a function which tells whether the office is open or closed. I have written a test case which is giving result as False but expecting True. I am not able to figure out reason.

```
    public class Office {
        public LocalTime openTime;
        public LocalTime closeTime;
        public LocalTime currentTime;
        
            public boolean isOfficeOpen() {
            currentTime = getCurrentTime();
    
            if (currentTime.isAfter(openTime)&&currentTime.isBefore(closeTime)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            
        }
        public LocalTime getCurrentTime(){ return  LocalTime.now(); }
    }

:

@Test
public void is_office_open_pass_test(){
    Office offc = Mockito.mock(Office.class);
    LocalTime openingTime = LocalTime.parse("10:30:00");
    LocalTime closingTime = LocalTime.parse("23:00:00");
    LocalTime currentTime = openingTime.plusHours(1);
    Mockito.when(offc.getCurrentTime()).thenReturn(currentTime);
    boolean status = offc.isOfficeOpen();
    assertTrue(status);
}
```

Comment: You're using a mock which doesn't have any behavior at all, so you can't call `isOfficeOpen` on it. If you need a partial mock, where you just mock your `getCurrentTime` method, you need a `Mockito.spy` instead.

Comment: Is there any other way to write this test? I am naïve to this hence missing out on few things

Comment: You are testing if the current time is between the opening time and the opening time: `if (currentTime.isAfter(Opentime)&&currentTime.isBefore(Opentime))`. Also, the name of the field should begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Why are you mocking the class under test? You should only mock its dependencies. You should inject a [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) into your class and use it when getting the current time, so you can control it in your test.

Comment: @DavidConrad Apologies for the typo, corrected it now in question:
if (currentTime.isAfter(openTime)&&currentTime.isBefore(closeTime)

Comment: If you initialize openingTime , closeTime in your test case, It wont reflect in the `isOfficeOpen ` method.

Comment: @Tris Can you please suggest an approach, how I can achieve it?

Comment: You are literally testing a mock which is not something you should do. Test implementation, mock dependencies

Comment: Change method param to `public boolean isOfficeOpen(openingTime , closingTime)`  and 
 pass `offc.isOfficeOpen(openingTime , closingTime)` in the test case. It will work. By the way this is not a good example to learn mockito.

Answer (score 0):

`Office.isOfficeOpen()` is never called. Instead the mock is used. But because you didn't provide any behaviour with `Mockito.when(offc.isOfficeOpen()).thenReturn(...);` Mockito just returns null/false and your test fails.

But the big question is: why are you using Mockito here instead of testing the class directly?

Comment: Idea to use Mockito was to mock current time. As per my understanding, If I create a test without it then test will give different results when run at different times. If I run it after close time, it will always fail.

Comment: I would pass the current time as a parameter to `isOfficeOpen()`. As a result you can test the behaviour of the method directly when called with different times. 
`assertTrue(new Office().isOfficeOpen(LocalTime.parse("14:00:00"));`
`assertFalse(new Office().isOfficeOpen(LocalTime.parse("23:30:00"));`

Try to keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: I have added example where you actually pass a provider.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to test a mock which is not something that you normally do. You should test implementation, and mock dependencies.

```
@AllArgsConstructor // if you are not using lombok, just create all args constructor yourself
public class Office {
    public LocalTime openTime;
    public LocalTime closeTime;
    public Producer<LocalTime> currentTimeProvider;
    
        public boolean isOfficeOpen() {
        currentTime = getCurrentTime();

        if (currentTime.isAfter(openTime)&&currentTime.isBefore(closeTime)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    public LocalTime getCurrentTime(){ return  this.currentTimeProvider.get() }
}
```

:

```
@Test
public void is_office_open_pass_test(){
    LocalTime openingTime = LocalTime.parse("10:30:00");
    LocalTime closingTime = LocalTime.parse("23:00:00");
    LocalTime currentTime = openingTime.plusHours(1);

    Office offc = new Office(openingTime,closingTime,()->currentTime)
    boolean status = offc.isOfficeOpen();
    assertTrue(status);
}
```